# Resizing enormous Cursors in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, mac, mouse-cursor

I just upgraded from QGIS 2.18 to 3 on my MacBook Pro (retina display, running High Sierra).  Some of the cursors are enormous and I can't figure out how to change their size.  For example, the Pan Map cursor is the normal size, but the Zoom In/Zoom Out cursors are about 2 or 3 times the normal size.  Screen shots show what I mean.

I don't have this problem with my iMac, so I'm wondering what's wrong on my MacBook Pro.  I don't think it's a retina screen issue, because it didn't have this issue with QGIS 2.18.

Any ideas?

[image: zoom in]

[image: pan map]

Comment: If it's a retina issue, it does not affect Win machines.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option under the Mac's **Accessibility**/**Display** settings, a slider which you can use to resize the cursor.

I'm on QGIS 3.01, Mac High Sierra and don't see any inconsistencies in cursor size but I'm on a non-retina display.

[image]

I only found this setting because the normal size is a bit too small for my liking (especially the text cursor).

You might want to check this setting in case it's not the default for some reason (I assume 'Normal' is the default, it looks like you have it set to maximum)

EDIT: This seems to have been noted [in this issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18622). Although the pointers appear the same size for me, some look smooth (system pointers like the hand and traditional pointer) and some look a bit pixellated (like the zoom in/out). But they look a lot better in 3.0 than they do in 2.18, the larger sizes look really bad in 2.18.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It appears to be a known issue.  Hopefully it'll get fixed in an upcoming release.